# Fixed length array and a forced unwrapping of the last and the first elements

Tags: swift

I have an array with 3 elements and want to take the first one and the last one elements.

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let first: String = array.first!
let last: String = array.last!
```

SwiftLint mark a force unwrap as a warning. Can I avoid a `forced unwrapping` when asking about the first and the last elements for a well known (defined) arrays?

I don't want to use a default values like in an example below

```
let first :String = array.first ?? ""
```

**Edit:**

Why am I asking about it? Because, I would like to avoid an warnings from the SwiftLint when using a forced unwrapping when asking for a first and a last element of an array which was defined by a literal and has enough elements to be sure that there is the first and the last element.

**Edit 2:**

I have found a name for what I was looking for. It's called Static-Sized Arrays. [Static-Sized Arrays discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/yet-another-fixed-size-array-spitball-session/6019/11) stoped in 2017 and there is no chance to use it.

Comment: *One can say...*. Ignore one for this example. And *should avoid* is not equal to *must not* .

Comment: please remove `: String` swift will infer the type from the assignment

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have typed it, just to explicitly say that I don't want an optionals

Comment: @Adobels, hi, i update my answer for your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with index:

```
let first = array[0]
let last = array[array.count - 1]
```

---

> Why am I asking about it? Because, I would like to avoid an warnings
>   from the SwiftLint when using a forced unwrapping when asking for a
>   first and a last element of an array which was defined by a literal
>   and has enough elements to be sure that there is the first and the
>   last element.

You can't really avoid to unwrap optional value, so if you only need it for two cases extensions can help here.

```
extension Collection {
    func first() -> Element {
        guard let first = self.first else {
            fatalError() // or maybe return any kind of default value?
        }
        return first
    }
}

let array = [1, 2]
array.first() // 1
```

And if it need to be only in one swift file you can place this code in that file and mark extensions with `private` keyword.

Comment: I have found a name for what I am asking for. It's called `Static-Sized Arrays`and is not implemented in Swift at this moment. https://forums.swift.org/t/yet-another-fixed-size-array-spitball-session/6019

Comment: it looks that in a case of an extension `fileprivate`is equal to `private`

Comment: @Adobels, `Static-Sized Arrays` discussion stoped in 2017 and there is no chance to use it. And yes,  `fileprivate` and `private` does the same thing here, but you should use the most restrictive access level (`private`) to help compiler make some low-level optimizations.

Comment: It would be great to have those details about `Static-Sized Arrays`in your answer

Comment: Swift doesn't have Static-Sized Arrays. The link you send just a discussion about possible implementation (again, it's **not implemented** in swift). It's unclear to me what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I avoid a forced unwrapping when asking about the first and the last elements for a well known (defined) arrays?

No you don't have to worry about it for a fixed array , actually the optional attachment for the properties `first` and `last` is designated to avoid crashes for an empty arrays

Comment: SwiftLint will label those lines with warnings. I will have to manually disable those warnings.

Comment: I get around this by not `guard`ing against `!a.isEmpty`, but by `guard let`ing `first` and `last` (which implicitly also checks for empty, while also unwrapping the optionals, all in one go).